# Octopus Deploy Dynamic Infrasture at Project Level

Tags: azure-web-app-service, octopus-deploy

In Octopus Deploy, each environment as a setting called Dynamic Infrasture. There is a checkbox to 'Allow dynamic infrastructure', and I have it turned on.

How can I turn this off at the project level?

I have one project that needs this off, but older projects need it on.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently possible to turn that feature off for a single project.

You could move the project to a different space, or create a new set of environments with a new lifecycle for that project only.

The Dynamic Infrastructure flag only affects how the deployment will accept [create target commands](https://octopus.com/docs/infrastructure/deployment-targets/dynamic-infrastructure/azure-web-app-target). If you aren't using those then it has no effect.